# SQL query to get records where first related record does not match

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables, something like this:

Leases
ID, LeaseDate

LeaseInvoices
ID, LeaseID, InvoiceDate, StartDate

How can I find all cases where LeaseDate does not match InvoiceDate of the invoice with the first StartDate?

I can't work out how to do it, something along these lines?

```
SELECT * FROM LeaseInvoice
INNER JOIN Leases ON Leases.ID = LeaseInvoices.LeaseID
WHERE LeaseDate IS NULL
OR LeaseDate <> (
    SELECT TOP 1 InvoiceDate FROM LeaseInvoices
    ORDER BY StartDate DESC
)
```

Comment: i dont fully understand your logic, but looking at it you should be able to get the Invoice dates you want using ROW_NUMBER () function

Comment: Maybe adding sample data and expected result would make this question more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this, e.g.:

```
SELECT
    ID
    , LeaseDate
    , InvoiceDate
    , StartDate
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            L.ID
            , L.LeaseDate
            , I.InvoiceDate
            , I.StartDate
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY L.ID ORDER BY I.StartDate) R
        FROM
            Leases L
            JOIN LeaseInvoices I ON L.ID = I.LeaseID
    ) Q
WHERE
    R = 1
    AND LeaseDate <> InvoiceDate
```